# Google sheets Hyper links to folders not working

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to migrate an Excel sheet to Google sheets and having a problem with the links to folders as can not get them to work. Tried to use this format:

=HYPERLINK("Folder/sub Folder","link label")

Is there a way to get the folders to open or is it just not possible because Google sheets is web based and the security permissions won't allow it to open a windows folder?

Comment: google sheets actually won't allow to add a local folder or directory and give error if you do it manually as google sheets have validation added for same. So, sorry you can't access local folders in google sheet and you shouldn't be actually for the security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The [HYPERLINK()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) function of Google Sheets requires as first parameter a URL.

If you want to include a link to a Google Drive folder you should use the URL of that folder. The sharing URl of a folder looks like the following one

```
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1B5xqUTMMK_n6NmdkTUhsbUd9SE0&usp=sharing
```

The URL of a folder taken from the Google Drive UI looks like the following one

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1B5xqUTMMK_n6NmdkTUhsbUd9SE0
```

Note: I changed some characters of the real folder ID to prevent access requests.